# Possible for an extension to get a query's result set / grid?

Tags: vscode-extensions, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to write an extension where the general flow of events is that:

1. a user runs a query in Azure Data Studio and gets a result set.
2. the user then either clicks a button or invokes an action from the command palette.
3. the extension retrieves the connection type (i.e.`providerId` such as `MSSQL`), the query itself, the schema of the columns returned and a sample of data (up to 5 rows).
4. the extension then uses this data for its broader business purpose.

I've successfully managed to get the `providerId` from the current connection. I've also successfully got the SQL using `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`.

However, I can't figure out a way of getting at the result set data at all to get the columns (names, data types, nullability if possible) or the data rows themselves.

Is there a way of doing this?

I have seen that another extension is obtaining the query and then re-running it in the background, which I'd rather not do if it happens to be a long-running query as it would give a poor user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to retrieve a sample set of rows from the result grid as follows:

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const connection = await azdata.connection.getCurrentConnection();
const queryProvider = azdata.dataprotocol.getProvider(connection.providerId, azdata.DataProviderType.QueryProvider) as azdata.QueryProvider;

const result = await queryProvider.getQueryRows({
  ownerUri: editor.document.uri.toString(), 
  rowsCount: 5
} as azdata.QueryExecuteSubsetParams);
```

However, I haven't found a way of getting the column metadata (e.g. names, data types, etc).

I've created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/24617) to address this.